# Do the Coefficients in a Power Series need to be constants?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

Apologies, this is a really basic question but I can't find a clear answer anywhere.

Suppose there is a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ that is analytic and you express it as a power series around $x_0$,

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x-x_0)^n$$

are the coefficients $a_n$ required to be strictly constants? In other words, can we instead express them as functions of x?

I've only seen it written that $a_n$ are real numbers, but $f$ maps to the reals, so I'm unsure about whether or not they can be written as functions of $x$.

Comment: No, $a_n$ doesn't depend on $x$. The $a_n$ will be given by $\frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}$.

Comment: The $a_n$ appearing in the power series expansion of $f$ are constants. Putting $f$ aside (as some $f$ are not given by their Taylor series), for basic results (e.g. computing the radius of convergence as the usual limit) of a power series, you do need those numbers be independent of $x$. Nothing prevents you from considering series with more general coefficients, however, they just may be harder to analyze. Do you have a particular case in mind?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $a_n$ are required to be constant in the definition of analytic functions.

---

In principle, you could consider functions of the form
$$
f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x) \cdot (x-x_0)^n,
$$
if you wished. But there's so much room that you could just choose
$$
a_0(x) := f(x), \quad a_1(x),a_2(x),\ldots := 0,
$$
so this form doesn't tell us much.